# Retrieve large number of documents elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an ElasticSearch database of roughly 20 million documents (each comprising some metadata and some text data). I'm interested in retrieving all the documents containing either of two keywords in the main text (say, "apple" and "banana"). I tried doing a quick search in Kibana and found 5 million hits. How can I export them all so that I can work with the dataset in python? Is there any way to do that in Kibana?

I have tried using the CSV export functionality in Kibana but it only exports 500 docs. The standard elasticsearch search API also limits the number of documents to 10000. What's the best way to retrieve all the 5m docs?
My end goal is to perform NLP on the retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract a bunch of data from elasticsearch, I recommend you to use `elasticdump`.
https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump

Here is an example:

```
elasticdump \
  --input=http://localhost:9200/your_index_name \
  --type=data \
  --searchBody='{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"match":{"main_text":"apple"}},{"match":{"main_text":"banana"}}]}}}' \
  --output=/path/to/output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

For large-scale clusters, I would recommend using Logstash and its [CSV output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-csv.html). Logstash is better suited for handling high-volume of data and gives more control over data transformation, should you need it.

I would choose elasticdump only for small to medium-sized Elasticsearch indices, for which the tool really shines.

If you are interested, you can find [here](https://github.com/glenacota/elastic-training-repo/tree/main/scenarios-to-go/logstash-es2csv) a demonstrative dockercompose + configs for the `elasticsearch -> logstash -> csv` scenario

Comment: If you don't want to mess up with Logstash but still need a CSV output, I'd recommend https://pypi.org/project/es2csv/